# Oracle, How to mount two databases from pfiles?

Tags: oracle

My hard disk crashed and I recovered oracle binary data. Basically, it contains two databases.

I'm able to mount each of the databases separately based on a configured PFILE. I create then the SPFILE to keep it as default database. (instructions here : [Link](http://oraclequirks.blogspot.fr/2008/05/ora-02095-specified-initialization.html))

The problem with that, is it always erases the previous configured database in the spfile and I'm unable to get both of them mounted.

Does anyone know please how to mount two databases based only on the binary files ? Is there any specific configuration to do on the spfile ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In order to run the instance(memory allocation+ background processes) we need spfile/pfile then we need control files(location pointed by `control_files` parameter in spfile/pfile) to mount the database. Do you have these control files which defines the these physical files? If you don't have and you know where these physical files are located then can create new control file.

Comment: Yes, I do have these control files. And again I'm able to mount each database separately. It would be difficult to mount them without control files...